# Self referring foreign key in sequlize js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I have a model 
*employee* `(id,first_name,last_name,manager_id)`

Here the `manager_id` is a self refering foreign key where it refers to the `id` column of the same table.
How do I implement such a use case in sequelize.

I tried this and this is not working

```
employee.belongsTo(models.employee, {
        foreignKey: 'manager_id'
      }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define association like :

```
employee.belongsTo(employee, {as: "Manager"});
employee.hasMany(employee, { as: "Employee", foreignKey: "manager_id", useJunctionTable: false });
```

And then use it like

```
employee.findAll({
    include : {
        model : employee ,
        as : 'Manager'
    }
})
```

OR

You can use **[sequelize-hierarchy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-hierarchy)**

```
var employee = sequelize.define('employee', {
    name: Sequelize.STRING,
    manager_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        hierarchy: true
    }
});

employee.findAll({ hierarchy: true }).then(function(results) {
    // results = [
    //  { id: 1, manager_id: null, name: 'a', children: [
    //      { id: 2, manager_id: 1, name: 'ab', children: [
    //          { id: 3, manager_id: 2, name: 'abc' }
    //      ] }
    //  ] }
    // ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sequlize guru. =)