# How to find parent hierarchy in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

How to fetch parent hierarchy of a category, below is my database (Postgress) and my expected JSON result. I wanted to display a category which is under another category which is under another and so on.

Database:

```
{ 

  id:1,

  name:cate1,

 parent_id:null

},

{

   id:2,

   name:cate2,

   parent_id:1

 },

{  

   id:3,

   name:cate3,

   parent_id:2

 }
```

Now I want my JSON result to be as follows

```
{

 id:3,

 name:cate3,

 parent_id:2,

 parent:{

    id:2,

    name:cate2,

    parent_id:1,

   parent:{

    id:1,

    name:cate1,

    parent_id:null

   }

 }

}
```

for id 3, So how to achieve this in sequelize js with node.

Comment: you need a recursive CTE query in postgre sql. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/

Comment: Here you go : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813479/self-referring-foreign-key-in-sequlize-js/53813977#53813977

Comment: thx for the replies.